# Characteristics of Araneus hui (an orb-weaving spider)

Tags: zoology, arachnology

What are the characteristics of *Araneus hui*? Neither thematic literature nor photos was found.

Mentioned in RU Wikipedia, reference wasn't found.
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8

Comment: I found a number of images via [Google Image Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=araneus+hui&tbm=isch)

Comment: @MattDMo none of those photos in your Google Image search were A.hui (at least in the first few hundred) There were all Araneus diadematus or A.clerk or other common Araneus species.

Comment: @Noah It would help to know what characteristics you might be looking for, and maybe a 'why' would help. We don't know if you are interested in, say, the what colour they mainly have, or whether it is has genetic similarity to another species, or its evolutionary phylogeny, or something else.

Comment: @JimN I apologize for not specifying in advance. The initial interest was precisely in the appearance, including it's color. That is why I initially tried to find photographs.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! In the future please [edit] your question rather than clarifying in the comments — comments are ephemeral and not read by everyone so essential information should not be included here. Please also check to make sure the changes I made are consistent with what you intended and make changes as needed. ——— You may also benefit from taking the [tour] and then going through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These pages cite papers that mention A.hui:

https://www.gbif.org/species/2160156

https://wsc.nmbe.ch/species/2910/Araneus_hui

The World Spider Catalog (WSC) offers papers to their users for free, and it is a free registration.

Browsing through the second pdf on the WSC, here is a sketch of the dorsal (top) view of the species:

[image]

The paper is primarily written in a language I cannot read.
The specific paper (book?) is:

Hu, J. L. (2001). Spiders in Qinghai-Tibet Plateau of China. Henan Science and Technology Publishing House, 658 pp.

658 pages is quite volumnous. The title of the paper suggests we limit our search to Tibet. Searching for Araneus images on iNaturalist in Tibet, there is a picture of one Araneus that has not been identified to species level, but it resembles the abdominal shape as in the drawing in the paper:

https://inaturalist.ca/observations/51273647

But the abdominal markings do not match at all. If you expand the geographical bounding box of the search around Tibet, you can browse a gallery of hundreds of possible pictures.

Comment: If anyone can translate the chinese characters in the 1. 2. 3. points in the footnote of the image, that would be great!

Comment: 1. Female back view .  2. external female organ  3.  external female organ dissection

Comment: @PolypipeWrangler Great, thanks!